# ionic3 dynamic images not rendering correctly on android

Tags: angular, html, typescript, ionic3, ionic4

hi i'm using img tag inside ion-scroll , then images appear correctly on ios and browser but when on android some of the images don't appear , so when i open the menu then close it the images appear . i don't know what happened someone have this scenario before?

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
          <div *ngFor="let image of Data.imgs"
               class="type-section" col-md-6 col-lg-4>
               <img class="sliderImg"
               [src]="image.img"/>
          </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

their another way also when i change the display css or height the images appear.

Answer (score 0):

i removed ion-scroll cz it seems there's conflict with images
so i replaced the `<ion-scroll>` with `<div class="items hideScrollBars styleA"> </div>`

```
.styleA{
    height: 180px;
    width: 100vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

so the images appear normal on android, browser and ios